# Extracting html data using perl script

Tags: perl, html

This is my code to extract certain data under the header `Item Drop%`. I want to extract the `90.5%` under that header. But i can only extract the whole column not just that value. any idea ?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::TableExtract;
use LWP::Simple;

my $file = 'data.html';
unless ( -e $file ) {
    my $rc = getstore(
        'proj/Desktop/folder1/data.html',
        $file);
    die "Failed to download document\n" unless $rc == 200;
}



my $te = HTML::TableExtract->new( headers => qw(Item Drop%)]);

$te->parse_file($file);

my ($table) = $te->tables;

foreach my $ts (ts->tables) {
    print "Table (", join(',', $ts->coords), ");\n";
    foreach my $row ($ts->rows) {
        print join(',', @$row), "\n";
    }
}
```

My `data.html` is:

```html
 ..
 ..
 ..
<table align = "center" class="" style= .......>
<tr>
<th rowspan="2">EM</th>
<th colspan="2"><a href= "proj/Desktop/folder1/data.html" class = ..../th>
<td> 90.5%</td>
</tr>
..
..
..
..
<tr>
<th rowspan="2">EM</th>
<th colspan="2"><a href= "proj/Desktop/folder1/data.html" class = ..../th>
<td> 40%</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Try removing the `attribs` or `headers` from the constructor.

Comment: i removed but it just extract the first table it sees

Comment: So try to identify the table somehow, i.e. `($te->tables)[1]` etc.

Comment: @choroba hi i have updated the question

Comment: Your script contains errors. Also, the HTML you provided doesn't demonstrate the problem you claim to have.

Comment: There is no `Item Drop%` in your example dataset

Comment: Advice to newcomers: If an answer solves your problem, please accept it by clicking the large check mark (✓) next to it and optionally also up-vote it (up-voting requires at least 15 reputation points). If you found other answers helpful, please up-vote them. Accepting and up-voting helps future readers.

Answer (score 1):

My though is that [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) is most of the time the better way for HTML scraping in any language, and not limited to tables. Perl's [`HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath) is a must have, and easily fetch your value, check:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict; use warnings;
use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;

my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new;
$tree->parse_file("./data.html");
print [$tree->findvalues('//table//td[contains(text(), "%")')]->[0];
```

##### Output

```
90.5%
```